# Using launchd or Lingon to schedule command between certain hours

Tags: macos, bash, launchd

Working on a Mac (Mavericks) and have a shell script that I would like to run every 5 minutes, between the hours of 9 to 5pm.  Outside of those hours I don't want it to run.

To run the script from the terminal, I issue the following command:

```
./script.sh < list.txt
```

Because I have to pass the list.txt file to the script, I've been having problems when trying to get launchd to run the script (at all, even without the schedule I want).  I've been using Lingon3 to create the plist (it works fine for other commands where I'm not passing a txt file to the script as I am in this situation).  I've also tried putting in the full path (

> /full/path/to/script.sh < /full/path/to/list.txt

)

And it doesn't work either.

Please help a) getting launchd to execute the command above and b) creating a plist which runs the command periodically between certain hours of the day.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can just list out each combination of hour and minute:

`for h in {9..17};do for m in $(seq 0 5 55);do echo "<dict><key>Hour</key><integer>$h</integer><key>Minute</key><integer>$m</integer></dict>";done;done`

You might also run the script every hour but exit it depending on the date:

```
hour=$(date +%H);[[ $hour -ge 9 && $hour -le 17 ]]||exit
```

Or use cron instead. Run `crontab -e` (or `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`) and add a line like this:

```
*/5 9-17 0 0 0 /full/path/to/script.sh < /full/path/to/list.txt
```

You can use `StandardInPath` to get stdin from a file:

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/full/path/to/script.sh</string>
<key>StandardInPath</key>
<string>/full/path/to/list.txt</string>
```

Or use `bash -c`:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>bash</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>/full/path/to/script.sh &lt; /full/path/to/list.txt</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I am new to launchd and wasn't able to get it working, so tried your cron example - when doing it, I received an error: `bad day-of-month` using your example

Answer (score 0):

launchd does not support cron style time specifications. You'd have to specify every five minute timestamp between 9AM and 5PM manually. [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl) allows you to specify the time interval cron-style and generates the corresponding keys for you:

[image: Config section in LaunchControl]